# Slicing a JSON array to get first five objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, arrays, slice

I have a JSON file wherein am reading the objects and displaying them in a div. But i just need to show only five of the objects rather than all.

Below is the code which i am using

```
$.each(recentActdata.slice(0,5), function(i, data) {
            var ul_data = "<li><h3>"+ renderActionLink(data)+ "</h3></li>";
            $("#recentActivities").append(ul_data);
        });
```

But this slice doesn't seems to work. The format of my JSON is

```
[   
{ 
    "displayValue":"Updated Guidelines", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"29/06/2013 01:32"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"Logging", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"28/06/2013 16:19"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"Subscribe", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"21/06/2013 14:30"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"Artifactory Vs Nexus", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"21/06/2013 13:39"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"CTT - Java 7", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"20/06/2013 13:30"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"Added Artifactory Server", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"19/06/2013 23:39"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"Estimation Template", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"19/06/2013 23:39"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"GZIP compression in Tomcat", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"14/06/2013 23:39"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"HBase Basics", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"12/06/2013 23:39"
}
 ]
```

Please suggest how to achieve this. I can't give my JSON a name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The code you posted works fine!**

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/enXcn/1/

Note how, when you are changeing the value of slice, more or less elements are displayed, which is what you discribed it should do.

```
HTML: <div id="recentActivities"></div>
```

JS:

```
var recentActdata = [   
{ 
    "displayValue":"Updated Guidelines", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"29/06/2013 01:32"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"Logging", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"28/06/2013 16:19"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"Subscribe", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"21/06/2013 14:30"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"Artifactory Vs Nexus", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"21/06/2013 13:39"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"CTT - Java 7", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"20/06/2013 13:30"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"Added Artifactory Server", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"19/06/2013 23:39"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"Estimation Template", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"19/06/2013 23:39"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"GZIP compression in Tomcat", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"14/06/2013 23:39"
},
{ 
    "displayValue":"HBase Basics", 
    "link":"#",
    "timestamp":"12/06/2013 23:39"
}
 ];


$.each(recentActdata.slice(0,5), function(i, data) {
            var ul_data = "<li><h3>"+ data.displayValue+ "</h3></li>";
            $("#recentActivities").append(ul_data);
        });
```

Comment: Well, basically, I am making an ajax call and the format of the file is same as i gave above but the thing is i cant add a name to my JSON array. This $each is inside the success function of ajax `success: function(recentActdata) {
       $.each(recentActdata.slice(0,5), function(i, data) {
    var ul_data = "<li><h3>"+ renderActionLink(data)+ "</h3></li>";
    $("#recentActivities").append(ul_data);
   });
    },`

Comment: Sorry. Yeah. the code in working fine, it was just some other mistake which i was not able to figure out. Thank you for the response.